# Why is Queue consuming so much memory?

Tags: c#, memory, queue

Basically I was doing a [code kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/double-cola/discuss) on codewars site to kinda of 'warm up' before starting to code, and noticed a problem that I don't know if its because of my code, or just regular thing.

```
public static string WhoIsNext(string[] names, long n)
{
    Queue<string> fifo = new Queue<string>(names);

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        var name = fifo.Dequeue();
        fifo.Enqueue(name);
        fifo.Enqueue(name);
    }
    return fifo.Peek();
}
```

And Is called like this:

```
// Test 1
string[] names = { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
long n = 1; 
var nth = CodeKata.WhoIsNext(names, n); // n = 1 Should return sheldon.

// test 2
string[] names = { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
long n = 52; 
var nth = CodeKata.WhoIsNext(names, n); // n = 52 Should return Penny.

// test 3
string[] names = { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
long n = 7230702951; 
var nth = CodeKata.WhoIsNext(names, n); // n = 52 Should return Leonard.
```

In this code When I put the long n  with the value 7230702951 (a really high number...), it throws an out of memory exception. Is the number **that** high, or is the queue just **not optimized** for such numbers.

I say this because I tried using a List and the list memory usage stayed under 500 MB (the plateu was around 327MB btw), and this running for about 2/3min, whereas the queue throwed the exception in a matter of seconds, and went over 2GB in just that time alone.

Can someone explain to me the why of this happening, I just curious?

**edit 1**

I forgot to add the List code:

```
public static string WhoIsNext(string[] names, long n)
{
    List<string> test = new List<string>(names);
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        var name = test[0];
        test.RemoveAt(0);

        test.Add(name);
        test.Add(name);
    }

    return test[0];
}
```

**edit 2**

For those saying that the code doubles the names and is inneficient, I already know that, the code isn't made to be useful, is just a kata. (I updated the link now!)

My question is as to why is Queue so much more inneficient thatn List with high count numbers.

Comment: Well, it depends on how many values are in `names` to start with, that could be lots and lots, which will obviously increase the memory used. Then you add them to your queue twice, it's not clear what this code is actually supposed to do.

Comment: the string[] names always starts with 5 names in the examples I show. Im just curious as to why the queue goes to over 2gb in a matter of seconds and list stays at 326MB constantly even whilst adding values, I mean I'm running the loop with the 7230702951 since I startted writing this question, and the memory usage doesn't increase anymore.

Comment: Not sure, you can check [Queue<T> code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,aa3beab99b2e0db2)  and [List<T> code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

Comment: The code is actually quite simple and short it's just that function actually, I'll update to show how I call the function though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the reason is that the queue code is **way** faster than the `List` code, because queues are optimised for deletes due to the fact that they are a circular buffer. *Lists aren't - the list **copies the array contents** every time you remove that first element*.

Change the input value to `72307000` for example. On my machine, the queue finishes that in less than a second. The list is still chugging away minutes (and at this rate, hours) later. *In 4 minutes `i` is now at 752408 - it has done almost 1% of the work).*

Thus, I am not sure the queue is less memory efficient. It is just **so fast** that you run into the memory issue sooner. The list almost certainly has the same issue (the way that `List` and `Queue` do array size doubling is very similar) - it will just likely take days to run into it.

*To a certain extent, you could predict this **even without running your code**. A queue with 7230702951 entries in it (running 64-bit) will take a **minimum** of 8 bytes per entry. So 57845623608 bytes. Which is larger than 50GB. Clearly your machine is going to struggle to fit that in RAM (plus .NET won't let you have an array that large)...*

Additionally, your code has a subtle bug. **The loop can't ever end** (if `n` is greater than `int.MaxValue`). Your loop variable is an `int` but the parameter is a `long`. Your `int` will overflow (from `int.MaxValue` to `int.MinValue` with `i++`). So the loop will never exit, for large values of `n` (meaning the queue will grow **forever**). You likely should change the type of `i` to `long`.

Comment: YES! I noticed that right now, and was writing an answer saying that. I think that the list is so slow that the garbage collector can just do his thing while the list keeps adding stuff, but the queue is just too fast! anyways, thank you for your answer!

Comment: To be precise, I _don't_ think GC is the **main** issue @ErickSantander. The nature of the array doubling system (used by both `List` and `Queue`) means that the 'excess' memory usage will be (at most) slightly less than the real memory usage. The problem isn't that `List`'s GC is keeping up. The problem is `List` is so damn slow that when `Queue` has processed 100% of the work, `List` has done less than 1% (well, more like less than 0.01%). No shock then that it has used less than 1% of the RAM. :)